# HP Syndra: Hardware Issues after switching from ChromeOS to Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone, touchscreen, speakers

I recently switched from ChromeOS to Ubuntu using the MrChromeBox BIOS/UEFI Firmware Update software. Everything is fine for the most part, and the only things that need to be fixed are:

- My Internal Speaker (and Mic) not being recognized
- The touchscreen not being responsive
- My 3.5mm Aux Jack not being recognized

When I go into the sound settings, all I get for Output Devices is `Dummy Output` and nothing is recognized for Input Devices.

However, in regards to the sound, I did notice while I was setting up Ubuntu 20.04, that the installation process stated that it was going to remove an `snd/sda` partition, which I knew had to do with sound, but I didn't know it would do this.

My system/machine details (I screenshot the about page in settings):

[image: My Machine Specs]

As in regards to the troubleshooting, the only thing that changed was that my sound output switched from `Dummy Output` to `HDMI Audio Output`

I haven't troubleshot the other issues yet, because the speaker issue is my top priority as or right now.

Comment: You've provided no details on what hardware you're using, how far you got with the troubleshooting procedure etc (which provides clues on detecting your hardware chipset details which are key to fixing issues) - How far did you get following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure (one of a number of pages; but some more are found just by following links on that page)

Comment: Sorry! Just posed about that below.